# Array subset optimization with composite aggregate functions

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, aggregate, subset

I have an array `P = [1, 5, 3, 6, 4, ...]` of size `N` and average `A`.

I want to find the most efficient way to maximize the following 3D function:

`f(x, y) = 1 / ( (1+e^(-6(x-2))) * (1+e^(-6(y-2))) * (1+e^(-0.1x-0.3y+1.5)) )`

[image: Function gcontour plot]

where `x = c(S) = Count(S)` and `y = m(S) = Min(S[0]/A, S[1]/A, ..., S[n]/A)`, and `S` is a subset of `P`. The subset does not have to be continuous in `P`.

I have a feeling that this can maybe be reduced to some variant of the subset sum problem but I really have no idea where to start other than sorting `P`. The goal is to implement the algorithm in PHP, but really any pseudocode would help a lot.

Comment: What is `S` in the equations? Or should that be `P`?

Comment: Let me edit that, it's a subset of P.

Comment: @Mat Probably https://math.stackexchange.com/ will be more suitable for this kind of question. I would say this is more related to math/optimisation than programming.

Comment: @mleko I definitely hesitated because I do wish to have the answer be compatible with PHP and because pseudocode seems more suitable here. I honestly don't know, you might be right.

Comment: @Mat, perhaps make it a two parter. Find the logic, and post back here if you need help implementing it in PHP?

Comment: Is it ok to just copy paste my problem on there to have it in both sites ?

Comment: @Mat I think it will be fine. You can cross link both questions

Comment: Probably need partial derivatives to get a maxima function, but, the issues you have are the subset problems as mentioned.

How large are you expecting N to get? Is it  bounded by something? Otherwise, you'll need to test different numbers and sets into the function to see if there is a trend or pattern.. ie. if smaller numbers or diff of numbers always trends higher, then you can skip some of the more complex sorting/organizing/permuting

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a clever math reduction, agree with others, the place is the math exchange.  Otherwise, start with the [Math_Combinatorics](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics) library.  Then you should be able to grind through all unique combinations of S with:

```
require_once 'Math/Combinatorics.php';
$combos = new Math_Combinatorics;

$P = [1, 5, 3, 6, 4, ...];
for ($n = 1; $n <= count($P); $n++) {
    foreach ($combos->combinations($P, $n) as $S) {
        ... your calculations on S go here ...
    }
}
```